# Why "PG::UndefinedColumn:" from a column who come from a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, migration

I've got a gem named Foo. In this gem I've got 2 branches : `master` and `develop`.

In my project I need to use the `develop` branch (which contain new migrations).
So in my gemfile I add :

`gem "foo", git: "https://github.com/orsay/foo.git", branch: "develop"`

Then run `bundle install` then re launch my server.

This is the error I get when I go on localhost:3000:

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column my_added_column does not exist`

Why does it happen ? I should not need to import migrations from the gem...

When I run `bundle show foo` the code is correct.

Any idea please ? :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @jvillian Yes I did. But nothing has been migrating

Answer (score 0):

Migrations defined in gems are not run when running `rake db:migrate`. Gems that wish to migrate the parent-app database should define a [Rails Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) which will make a rake task available to install the gems migrations in the host app. For example, in your case (where the Gem is `foo`) that would be `bundle exec rake foo:install:migrations`. Your gem must be properly configured as a Rails engine to do this.

As an alternative to installing the migrations, you can use an initializer to automatically run the migrations in a required gem if you'd rather do that, but it's a bit more complex. There's more detail on that in [Syncing Migrations](http://paulserraino.com/rails/2016/02/29/rails-mountable-engines.html)